# Comma between a which clause and an "and"

Tags: commas

> We have parsley, which is needed for flavour, and beer, which we can use for the marinade.

Should there be a comma before the "and"? I think there should be to make the sentence structure easier to understand, however Grammarly tells me otherwise.

Comment: A clearer question would use the real words for all those "something"s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grammarly, in particular, likes to avoid using a comma before "and" except when the following structure is a complete clause without any parallel ellipsis. Grammarly doesn't like:

> John went to the restaurant, and ate the largest pie on the menu.

Because the part following "and" isn't a complete clause.

It seems that your Grammarly (but not my Grammarly) is seeing the part following the comma as being an incomplete clause (true) and not noticing that in fact the commas are paired and surrounding the (parenthetical) relative clause.

> We have parsley, which is needed for flavour, and beer, which we can use for the marinade.

My Grammarly doesn't see any mistake in this.

And you *need* the comma, otherwise it reads that "we need parsely for flavour and we need parsely for beer"

Comment: I think we all would benefit from entirely ignoring whatever grammarly does, and just arriving at the right conclusion on our own.

Comment: I don't really agree.  Grammarly and other grammar and spelling checkers are useful. They are a tool, and can be both used and misused. The interesting fact is that My Grammarly and the OP's Grammarly are giving different results.  It's not clear why.